# Wordpress "wpdb->update" - Append Text Value

Tags: wpdb

I am trying to update a table column by appending some text to the existing value in the column.

Basically, I am trying to do something like this:

```
  $wpdb->update('table_name',
                array('notes' => notes + 'some text here to append'))
               ,array('note_id' => 313)
               );
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: it's not possible.

Long answer: you should try `$wpdb->query` instead and write a regular SQL query, something like this:

`UPDATE table_name SET notes = CONCAT(notes, 'text to append') WHERE note_id = '313'`

Please note it's only an example and you should use `$wpdb->prepare` to also sanitize variables properly.